# How to fix a rotated footer?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=16.5mm, right= 16.5mm, top=0mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\rotatebox{90}{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}}
}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{specialfooter}

\begin{center}
  \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{UNSW_HDR.png}}
\end{center}
   

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}} 

\section*{\normalsize{Outline how you are eligible for admission to the program.}}
  
\section*{\normalsize{Describe your capability to carry out high quality research.}}
 
\section*{\normalsize{Provide a rationale for why you chose this project and this supervisory team.}}


\clearpage
  
\newgeometry{left=16.5mm, right= 16.5mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{Research Project Description}\\
    Your research project description should include a statement of the research problem and its significance. You need to provide an outline of how you plan to address the problem. As different Faculties have different requirements (such as word-count and level of detail), you should discuss with your proposed supervisory team what is required.
\end{center}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}} 

\end{document}
```

The cropped output is as follows-
[image]

My queries are-

1. How can I fix the rotated footer (marked in red) in page 1? It should be on the right margin.
2. What is causing the horizontal line at the beginning of page 2 (marked in green)?

Comment: Why are you using `\rotatebox{90}{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}` in your `specialfooter` if you don't want it?

Comment: If you want the rotated "footer" in the marginpar area, use `\fancyfoot[R]{\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\smash{\rotatebox{90}{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}}}}`      Fancyhdr does not like text to exceed the header or footer areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions from John Kormylo solved the issue. Used the following code- `\fancyfoot[R]{\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\smash{\rotatebox{90}{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}}}}`

Answer (score 1):

hm, something like this?

[image]

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin= 16.5mm, vmargin={0mm,25mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % should be here
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}

\fancypagestyle{specialfooter}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}} % remove rotatebox

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{specialfooter}

\begin{center}
unknown image \verb+UNSW_HDR+%\includegraphics[width=\textidth]{UNSW_HDR.png}}
\end{center}

\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}

\section*{Outline how you are eligible for admission to the program.}

\section*{Describe your capability to carry out high quality research.}

\section*{Provide a rationale for why you chose this project and this supervisory team.}

\clearpage
\newgeometry{left=16.5mm, right= 16.5mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{Research Project Description}\\
    Your research project description should include a statement of the research problem and its significance. You need to provide an outline of how you plan to address the problem. As different Faculties have different requirements (such as word-count and level of detail), you should discuss with your proposed supervisory team what is required.
\end{center}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{1pt}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Suggestions from John Kormylo solved the issue.
Used the following code-
`\fancyfoot[R]{\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\smash{\rotatebox{90}{CRICOS Provider Code 00098G}}}}`

Comment: Could you please tell me what is causing the horizontal line (marked in green) as shown in the main post?

Comment: @RounakNiloy, this should be (self )evident from comment in answer code. You not eliminirate it in `fancy` page style.  Sorry, but now I'm nor sure if I correctly understood your question, so I can't help you further.

Comment: I could resolve the issue. I missed `\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} ` this segment. Thanks to your answer. Adding this line solved the issue.